# Full width image in a ListView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am using this [ImageLoader](https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader) Library for my ListView. It by default decodes the file to a 70px bitmap. But then I changed it to 1000, and the image I get is proper. The only problem is displaying the image in the `ImageView`.

The `ImageView` in the **ListItem** is like this:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

This displays an image which is centered in the ImageView, with proper aspect ration(no stretching etc..) and has empty spaces on all sides. The empty spaces might be because of the lower dimensions of the image.

I want the image to take complete width of the screen, and maintain the aspect ration. How do I get it?

**I tried:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

But then the image is stretched horizontally and completely out of aspect ration. Looks like its taking the height same as the actual image height but width as fill_parent.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/name"
        />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Make `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.
Set height to some arbit but legit value to begin with like `android:layout_height="0dp"`.
And for height, since there is no appropriate scaleType to get the aspect ratio the way you desire (i believe - confirm that developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/…), what you will have to do is in the java file, get the image's width and then set the height according to aspect ratio you need (0.6 in your case).

Comment: This is same as what am using right now. The problem with this is, it wont take the complete width. I want the image to take complete width and still maintain the aspect ratio. **eg: If the image is 500x300(w x h) it must be displayed as 400 x 240 on a device with width as 400dp and 1000 x 600 on a device with width as 1000dp**

Comment: I see. Then make android:layout_width="match_parent". And for height, since there is no appropriate scaleType (i believe - confirm that http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html), what you will have to do is in the java file, get the image's width and then set the height according to aspect ratio you need (0.6 in your case).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
```

Comment: This is taking the full width and maintaining the aspect ration, but the image is crop to center, hence I am missing the top and bottom parts of the image :( I tried replacing it with `fitXY` then comes back to the old stretched horizontally :(

Comment: Can you please use android:scaleType="centerInside" and let me know if it works? I'll make an edit accordingly.